# Can we show for every natural number can be represent in sum of two prime power

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question**

show that for every $n$ represents as, $n = p^x+ q^y$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p,q$ are primes and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n=149$ has no such representation, since one of the summands would have to be even and hence a power of $2$, and none of
\begin{multline*}
149-2^1=147,\quad
149-2^2=145,\quad
149-2^3=141,\\
149-2^4=133,\quad
149-2^5=117,\quad
149-2^6=85,\quad
149-2^7=21
\end{multline*}
is a power of a prime.

In general, the number of powers of $2$ up to $x$ has magnitude $\log x$ while the number of odd prime powers up to $x$ has magnitude $x/\log x$, so the number of such odd sums counting multiplicity has magnitude $x$; it would be quite a conspiracy if these managed to cover all odd integers up to $x$.

Comment: In fact $149$ is the smallest such number. The first few are $149, 179, 183, 193, \ldots$. This sequence does not seem to appear in the OEIS. I would guess that the question for even integers is difficult.

Comment: Are they infinity many?

Comment: @Pruthviraj Presumably, by the heuristic I alluded to in my answer. Someone might have even proved this.

Comment: @Travis The question for even integers is essentially the Goldbach conjecture; OP's set of conditions with $x=y=1$

Comment: @KeithBackman Right, and in particular the Goldbach conjecture is a stronger statement, since there one doesn't have the flexibility of taking powers of the primes before adding them. But it's not clear (to me, anyway) how much this additional flexibility buys you. It's conceivable to me that this isn't much easier than Goldbach, but I would be happy to see a demonstration that that's not true.